# Windows Mobile - Configure MMS and APN C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I referred to many links on internet for configuration of networks on windows mobile. But, can't find exact code to configuration MMS and APN using C# (.NET CF). Can anybody please provide exact code for the same?

Comment: Does windows mobile has any setting screen where I can see all available APNs?

Answer (score 2):

```
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Configuration;

var xml = File.OpenText(configFile).ReadToEnd();
var configDoc = new XmlDocument();
configDoc.LoadXml(xml);
ConfigurationManager.ProcessConfiguration(configDoc, false);
```

This will configure the APN connection as defined by the following config file:

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
<characteristic type="CM_GPRSEntries">
   <characteristic type="Default_APN">
      <parm name="DestId"   value="{18AD9FBD-F716-ACB6-FD8A-1965DB95B814}" />
      <parm name="AlwaysOn" value="1" />     
      <characteristic type="DevSpecificCellular">     
         <parm name="GPRSInfoValid" value="1" />
         <parm name="GPRSInfoAccessPointName"  value="yourAPNAddress.aw.co.uk" />
      </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
  </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

Comment: This will add GPRS settings. right? What is the difference between GPRS and APN?

Comment: Yes it will add the GRPS settings.  An APN (Access Point Name) is just an endpoint for the GRPS connection.

Comment: Thank you. What are the different types of APNs I can have? Like GPRS, Wi-Fi etc.. I have examples of each at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms890704.aspx. But, don't know which are required for APN settings.